# SQL two select queries two table as one results 4 fields

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Good day

Could you please help, I have two tables the structure is exactly the same however the one is basically a copy of the other which I refer to as the "original" because the live one is updated. I need to do a count on the same field of each table but with its unique date. So I want the count and date fields  for each table but in one result i.e. 4 fields. I need this for SSRS report that I am busy with.

I have tried union but it just counts all into one row and displays it in one field with one date.

My query is as follows:

```
Select count (payhist.AC_CODEID) as Actual,PAYHIST.PH_DATE as d1 from PAYHIST
join Paymonth on PAYHIST.PH_DATE >= Paymonth.ph_datesd  and  PAYHIST.PH_DATE <= Paymonth.ph_dateed 
where Paymonth.CurrentPD = 1
and PH_EXCEPTION = 1



Select count (PAYHISTTEMP.MST_SQ) as Original,PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE as d2  from PAYHISTTEMP
join Paymonth on PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE >= Paymonth.ph_datesd  and  PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE <= Paymonth.ph_dateed 
where Paymonth.CurrentPD = 1)
 group by PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE)
```

Comment: can you show your desire output ?

Comment: I want something like this:Actual 5, Date1 2018-01-16,Original 10, Date2 2018-01-16

Comment: But in 4 columns with unique column names

Comment: join this two query result on date than you have what you want

Comment: That's the thing I am not sure how? All the dates might not be in the one table as in the other because in one it gets removed. I am looking for a specific date period form 16 of a month until 15 of the next month. If possible it must add 0's if there is no count for that date

Comment: than you should check how to get dynamic date from query and join it with your two query

Answer (score 0):

Just another way,

```
  SELECT DATE, SUM(COUNT1) AS COUNT1, SUM(COUNT2) AS COUNT2
    FROM (
     SELECT DATE, COUNT1, 0 AS COUNT2 
       FROM TABLE1 WHERE .... GROUP BY DATE
      UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE, 0 AS COUNT1, COUNT2 
       FROM TABLE2 WHERE .... GROUP BY DATE
  ) TMP
  GROUP BY DATE
```

Comment: can you remove your answer? it is not what he is looking for

Comment: ok i see now what he is looking for and updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT ISNULL(Act.Actual,0) Actual, Act.d1, ISNULL(Org.Original,0) Original, Org.d2 FROM 
(
    Select count (payhist.AC_CODEID) as Actual,PAYHIST.PH_DATE as d1 from PAYHIST
    join Paymonth on PAYHIST.PH_DATE >= Paymonth.ph_datesd  and  PAYHIST.PH_DATE <= Paymonth.ph_dateed 
    where Paymonth.CurrentPD = 1
    and PH_EXCEPTION = 1
    GROUP BY PAYHIST.PH_DATE 
) AS Act
FULL JOIN 
(
    Select count (PAYHISTTEMP.MST_SQ) as Original,PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE as d2  from PAYHISTTEMP
    join Paymonth on PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE >= Paymonth.ph_datesd  and  PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE <= Paymonth.ph_dateed 
    where Paymonth.CurrentPD = 1
     group by PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE
) AS Org ON Act.d1 = Org.d2
```

Comment: I get the following: 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'PH_DATE'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'PH_DATE'

Comment: Serkan thank you this is exactly what I wanted. Many thanks

Comment: Is there a way to make the null values 0 if it is null in the query

Comment: The ISNULL function can be used to make this.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN two select statements on the date column. Try this

```
 SELECT * FROM

(Select COUNT(payhist.AC_CODEID) AS Actual,PAYHIST.PH_DATE as d1 FROM PAYHIST
   JOIN Paymonth ON PAYHIST.PH_DATE >= Paymonth.ph_datesd  AND
   PAYHIST.PH_DATE  <= Paymonth.ph_dateed 
   WHERE Paymonth.CurrentPD = 1 AND PH_EXCEPTION = 1
) t1

INNER JOIN

(SELECT COUNT (PAYHISTTEMP.MST_SQ) AS Original,PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE AS d2  FROM PAYHISTTEMP
JOIN Paymonth on PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE >= Paymonth.ph_datesd  AND PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE <= Paymonth.ph_dateed 
WHERE Paymonth.CurrentPD = 1
 GROUP BY PAYHISTTEMP.PH_DATE) t2
ON t1.d1 = t2.d2
```

Comment: Hi Bibin, I get the following:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

Comment: @GerhardSteyn: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks Bibin, this also works if I add the group by clause in the top query. Thank you

Comment: Another thing it doen't display the dates if there are only values in one table for a specified date